Mobile Connection page missing in Settings and tray
I have tried to add back the missing settings. The toggle bottom under the tray is also missing, but no success. Please advise how can I add them back? (i.e.: Mobile Connection icon under tray, see screenshot below). So I can't switch the mobile network on or off via GUI.

